# Either win or we're to win

Tags: usage

Of the following two sentences which one is more idiomatic

> If he wins the prize I would be very happy.

> If he were to win the prize I would be very happy.

I don't think the second one is correct but according to my book it is correct

Comment: the second one is perfectly correct, while I would rather say: "if he was to" for colloquial speech.

Comment: In an answer to another one of your questions, I explained that you are not using the word 'idiomatic' correctly. These are not idiomatic usages, they are literal usages.

Comment: @kandyman Agree on that. This is the type of question that should be tagged "grammar" or something else, and it can't be considered "idiomatic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the second one is fine, but the first one should be:

> If he wins the prize I **will** be very happy.

The first one seems more idiomatic to me; I’d certainly favour it in speech, with the second one feeling a bit too wordy/formal.

Comment: But would can also be used to "express the result of an action that you imagine".  Example She would be a fool to accept it. Then why is "would" not correct in this sentence?

Comment: That sentence is correct. It has to do with tense. Consider the following: “She would be a fool if she accepted it” (correct); “She would be a fool if she accepts it” (incorrect).